# Scala way to transform an array of points

Tags: scala

I have an array of points. To each point except the first I would like to subtract the previous:

`Array((1,1), (3,1), (4,3))` becomes `Array((1,1), (2,0), (1,2))`

I've come up with a "sort of" functional style:

```
val trans = for (i <- 0 until points.length - 1) 
  yield {
    (points(i + 1)._1 - points(i)._1, points(i + 1)._2 - points(i)._2)
}
val result = trans ++ points
```

But I feel it could be done better. After I complete the transformation I am then going to want to add all the tuples in `result`.

Comment: "After I complete the transformation I am then going to want to add all the tuples in result.". Are you sure? That's just the last element of your array (assume the  array is a, b, c, d. After your transform, a, b -a, c -b, d -c. Add them all up, result is just d.

Comment: Oops, I had `to` and `until` mixed apparently, will delete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically the for-comprehension you wrote is done via `zip`:

```
(xs zip xs.drop(1)).map{ case ((x1,y1), (x2,y2)) => (x2-x1, y2-y1) }
```

The rest (adding the first element) is special-purpose enough that you're pretty much on your own.  (You could add `(0,0)` to the front of `xs.drop(1)`, or prepend `xs.take(1)` to the result.)

Also, note that it is entirely possible to write the whole algorithm with sum as a single fold or recursion.

(I'm assuming you're not performance-limited here.)

Comment: Actually I will be doing this to millions of points across a cluster so speed is a factor.

Comment: @Chris - Millions of points still isn't very many; a single machine can handle that.  But if you are performance-limited, switch to arrays which hold each index separately (or hold them in even-odd pairs) and you will speed your code up by a factor of 20.  Write a recursive function or a while loop to process them.

Comment: That makes sense, avoid the tuple overhead.

Answer (score 4):

Consider

```
type Point = (Int,Int)

def sub( p1: Point, p2: Point ) = (p1._1 - p2._1, p1._2 - p2._2)
```

and so for

```
val points = Array((1,1), (3,1), (4,3))

for ((p1, p2) <- points.zip(points.drop(1)) yield sub(p2,p1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also `sliding` method for `Array`:

```
(Iterator(xs(0)) ++
  xs.sliding(2)
    .map { case Array((x1, y1), (x2, y2)) =>
             (x2 - x1, y2 - y1) }).toArray
//> res0: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((1,1), (2,0), (1,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function to do that:

```
type Pairs = Array[(Int,Int)]
def diff(seq: Pairs): Pairs = Array(seq.head) ++ seq.sliding(2).map{case Array((a1,b1),(a2,b2)) => (a2-a1, b2-b1)}
```

The you can use it in the REPL:

```
scala> diff(Array((1,1), (3,1), (4,3)))
res1: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((1,1), (2,0), (1,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is pretty close to elms . . . but I'm afraid his one is actually buggy since it is A) missing an parenthesis before the yield and B) is skipping the first element. So his result is `Array((2,0), (1,2))`. Sadly I can't comment on his solution for I don't have enough reputation. So here's my solution:

```
implicit class PointUtils( val point:(Int, Int) ) extends AnyVal {
  def subtract(other:(Int, Int)) = ( point._1 - other._1, point._2 - other._2 )
}

val points = Array((1,1), (3,1), (4,3))

for( (p1, p2) <- points.zip( (0,0) +: points ) ) yield p1.subtract( p2 )

//alternatively
points.zip( (0,0) +: points ).map( t => t._1.subtract(t._2) )
```

I've got a slight preference for implicit classes but many people would argue that elms `def sub(...)` is easier to understand.

Also note that my version uses more memory than elms because `(0,0) +: points` needs to copy the `points` array where `points.drop(1)` doesn't. That memory hit disappears though when you use Lists.